# How to modify strings pre-build

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Say I have the following code which contains a string

```
const char* fmt = L"%s";

int main()
{
    printf(fmt, L"hello");
}
```

Before I compile, I'd like an event to occur which transforms my source code, such that all strings are wrapped by a function. The final code should be like

```
const char* fmt = w2mb(L"%s");

int main()
{
    printf(fmt, w2mb(L"hello"));
}
```

Intelisense can identify strings so I know it is possible. How can I go about doing this? I figure it relates to pre-build events.

Comment: I cannot really understand what you are asking. Please rephrase your question! That being said, it seems like you are searching for something like https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt or https://abseil.io/docs/cpp/guides/format Plus, you maybe want logging sooner or later, thus I recommend having a look at https://github.com/gabime/spdlog (which uses fmt).

Comment: Why don't you use `wprintf`, or drop `L` prefixes? I'm not sure how you are even going to implement `w2mb` in a way that doesn't leak memory. This sounds line an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: By the way, this looks more like C, not C++.

Comment: `This will obviously not compile.` What compile errors are you getting? Are you asking solely about the compile errors?

Comment: @jan.sende It has nothing to do with the strings themselves, but an operation done to my source code before compilation

Comment: @IgorTandetnik this is an example, please focus on the question

Comment: @Chipster I am working in C++ so I specified that. The fact that the code works in C is just coincidence

Comment: @Chipster Type errors. a `char*` cannot be cast as a `wchar_t*` implicitly

Comment: @manofasdf Could you clarify what you mean by prebuild events?

Comment: @Chipster That's literally the question. Visual Studio has a project property that is "prebuild event" and I'd like to know how it exactly works and if it's usable in my situation.

Comment: *"please focus on the question"* Well, when one is faced with an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), the wise course of action is in fact to not focus on the immediate question (the Y), but to try and figure out what the questioner really wants to achieve (the X). What you are asking for is a really weird thing to want to do; there's likely a better, easier way to solve your real problem, if only you would explain what it is.

Comment: I made an edit. What you want is a pre-build transformation. (A transformation before the build.) Not a prebuild event. (An already built event.) My question is... Why? What do you want achieve with this? Why not just start with the already transformed code?

Answer (score 1):

Pre-build events are just command-line commands that are run prior to running the compiler.  If you want to wrap all the string constants in your program with a function you're going to need to write a preprocessor that carries this out.  That, in turn, is going to require hooking into a C++ compiler frontend.  I know that Roslyn makes this sort of thing fairly nice for C# but I don't know what's available for C++.  You might look into clang, which I think is what Visual Studio Code uses for its plugins; as far as I know, MSVC isn't an open-source compiler.

Of course if you're working with a limited selection of files formatted in particularly nice ways you might not need the full power of a C++ parser; you might even be able to get away with a regex or something.

That said this seems like a pretty weird thing to do, and you might want to consider whether you can rearrange things to avoid having to do this.

Comment: "If you want to wrap all the string constants in your program with a function you're going to need to write a preprocessor that carries this out" Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: You'll have to write your own program, likely from scratch, that carries out that transformation on your source files.

Comment: You could do that, but I'd recommend having it produce temporary files with a different extension or something instead.  (That said, what I'd *actually* recommend is not doing this at all -- why do you want a bunch of .cpp files that won't compile lying around?)

Comment: They'll compile. Prebuild duplicates `Source.cpp` into `Source.cpp.bak` and then the original `Source.cpp` is modified like is desired in the question. Compilation ensues. Postbuild deletes `Source.cpp` and renames `Source.cpp.bak` back into `Source.cpp`. Now to somehow make a way to identify strings from a file... :P

Comment: I agree that that is a viable way to do what you're asking to do, although from a software engineering perspective it's not a course of action I recommend.